# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' when using CrafterCMS with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, crafter-cms

I'm trying to create a crafterCMS project with typescript. I install the latest packages:

```
"@craftercms/content": "^2.0.7",
"@craftercms/experience-builder": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
"@craftercms/ice": "^2.0.7",
```

But when i run the project i get this error:
[image]

By checking the logs its coming from a file belonging to @craftercms/experience-builder in node_modules:

[image]

If i don't use typescript i dont get any errors so my guess its because of these typescript files in node_modules:

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: The question is a bit short on details. What's your stack? Share some of the code that's generating this. At the moment the package is only shipped in module format (no commonjs). Could be related to that but need more details to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem using next transpile modules.
I added

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@craftercms/experience-builder','@craftercms/studio-ui']);
```

to `next.config.js` and then export using that

```js
module.exports = withTM({...});
```